# how i can remove uitableview section when that section data is null in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have 5 sections in my tableview. I am passing 5 different arrays to 5 sections.
Sometimes I am getting some arrays that are empty. I then want to remove that section.

Ex:I have array 1,2,3,4,5 and I am passing array 1 to section1 .....array 5 to section 5.

I am getting data from webservices. Sometimes array 1 & 4 are null. When that happens, I want to show 3 sections: 
array2 in section1
array3 in section2
array5 in section3

Next time, maybe arrays 3, 4 & 5 are null. Then I want to show 2 sections: 
array1 in section1
array2 in section2

Randomly i get null-values from webservices.

How can I show the data in sections based on array count?

Comment: How do you `passing array 1 to section1 ....`?

Comment: by using if condition,if(section==0){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep all your non empty arrays in a single array let's say `containerArray`.

```
NSMutableArray *containerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Where you receive response add these lines:

```
if([array1 count] > 0) {
    [containerArray addObject:array1];
}
if([array2 count] > 0) {
    [containerArray addObject:array2];
}
if([array3 count] > 0) {
    [containerArray addObject:array3];
}
if([array4 count] > 0) {
    [containerArray addObject:array4];
}
if([array5 count] > 0) {
    [containerArray addObject:array5];
}

[_tableView reloadData];
```

Implement `UITableView` methods as:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [containerArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[containerArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //retrieve array from containerArray at indexPath.section and and draw cells for array elements at indexPath.row.
}
```